# Manual placement of figures in Latex document

Tags: graphics

I am using the figure environment for placing figure at the bottom of the page as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
........
\end{figure}
```

But, my figure is being placed at the top of the page and "[b]" is being printed along with figure. What can be the reason for this? I am using the figure-related packages -- "graphicx" and "subcaption"..

Comment: Can you give us a Minimal Working Example ?

Comment: You could for example be using a documentclass that redefines the `figure` environment to not have an optional argument, but it is impossible to say for certain without more information.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to put the figure to the bottom of a page is to tell latex to put directly to the bottom by `\begin{figure}**[!b]**`

You can look at the result by looking [at this code](https://ru.sharelatex.com/project/565c118c71a50b5253b56107). The code itself is here:

```
%% Just a MWE with a figure of a kitten and blindtext package

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} %% For better viewing the result of figure placement
\usepackage{blindtext} %% add blind text around an image
\usepackage{droid} %% Doesn't matter, I just like that font
\usepackage{graphicx} %% turning on images support. I prefer EPS.
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\title{Figures placement}
\author{texnicker.bookman2016 }
\date{November 2015}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%% The case with putting an image on the bottom. For that you need to "ask" LaTeX to put directly at the bottom of the page
\section{Example}

%% Let's insert a picture around blind text
\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{cat}
\caption{A cat!}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: `**...**` markup does not work inside `\`...\`` tags

Comment: This is unlikely to be the answer, if the OP's `\begin{figure}[b]` is printing `[b]` then this will print `[!b]`.  Also you shouldn't routinely use `!` It doesn't make sense to set constraints and then routinely ignore them, better to set appropriator constraints.

Comment: The are limits to how large a figure can be on the bottom (0.3\textheight IIRC).  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat?s=1|1.9364